# General stats on RPC endpoint?

Tags: rpc

I was using the public mainnet-beta RPC endpoint for my Dapp until I started getting 403 from the API. I am starting to look at private RPC.

I am still quite confused on what is the price for one request for example, do you have an idea or do you know the global stats ?

I want to build a totally decentralised static website (no backend, just calling smart contracts sometimes) and push it to IPFS.

I will need a private RPC node from what I understand and I feel like it will make the website less decentralised because it relies on me paying the node basically, do you see a better solution for my issue ? Or maybe a private RPC is cheap and I can afford it.

Have a good day,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept is that for real production use by clients, you should not rely on the free public nodes. If you don't mind the public RPC nodes potentially being down, then keep using them. If you need to always serve the site, you should provision your own RPC node.

I won't use this space to advertise for other companies, but you can search around for Solana RPC node providers and compare their options and pricing.